# Loading a scene by a scene name (string) stored in List not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a scene by using the scene name. The scene names are stored in  a list of strings that are derived from the names of objects(scenes) that populate a public array (so I can add the scenes in the editor). When I call SceneManager.LoadScene I'm using an item from the list for the scene name `forestSceneNames[i]`. In Debug.Log it is returning the scene name but the scene is not loading when I start the app. Why is this not working?

```
public Object[] forestScenes;
private List<string> forestSceneNames;

// Initialize scene name list
for (int i = 0; i < forestScenes.Length; i++)
{
    forestSceneNames.Add(forestScenes[i].name);
}
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

Debug.Log("Trying to load " + forestSceneNames[1]);
SceneManager.LoadScene(forestSceneNames[1], LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

Comment: Wrong name? What happens if you hard-code the name of a scene that you *know* (I mean really *know* know, not wild guess, hazy conjecture, or optimistic assumption) exists?

Comment: Why are you doing `forestSceneNames[i].ToString()`? Isn't `forestSceneNames[i]` already a string?

Comment: I took ToString() off the end. It's still not working, my mistake on that one.

Comment: AFAIK scene must be added into build to be loaded by scene manager, but you should have accurate error message in log.

Comment: Yes, the scene is added to the build settings. Where can I find the error log?

Comment: Create a simple function to log data to a .txt file and debug what forestSceneNames[1] actually is during runtime. Also debuc the size of your Object[].. I'm wondering if it is being cleared whenever you build the game.

Comment: Is this your actual code? What you have posted wouldn't compile, you cannot do `forestScenes[i].name` as `forestScenes` contains an array of `object`. Something is missing here.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Why would you make explicit function when all logs are saved into Data/log file in builds?

Comment: Use whichever logging mechanism you'd like. The point is to see what your data looks like at runtime on a build. I'm pretty sure that the Object[] is being cleared because, and I may be wrong here, but if you want things like that to persist in a build, shouldn't you add them to a "Resources" folder? Otherwise your scenes and their data will be packaged with the binary.